# Rect.contains() not returning true even though the values are contained

Tags: android, 2d, ontouchlistener, rect

I'm trying to make a simple drag and drop game. In order to not have to setTouchListeners on every view separately, I set in on the layout.

The approach that I want to use for filtering out touches which are not placed on the object itself is asking if the rect of the view contains the coordinates I get form event.getX() and Y respectively.

I've printed out a toast to make sure that it indeed does contain the coordinates, and it does.

Yet the event is not registering as true.

Could you please help?

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "GameActivity";

    private float x;
    private float y;

    private Integer currentXInt;
    private Integer currentYInt;


    ConstraintLayout mLayout = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.GameActivityID);
        final View viewTest = findViewById(R.id.viewTest);

       mLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                Rect viewTestRect = new Rect(viewTest.getLeft(),viewTest.getRight(),viewTest.getTop(),viewTest.getBottom());

                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();

                currentXInt = Math.round(event.getX());
                currentYInt = Math.round(event.getY());

                if(viewTestRect.contains(currentXInt,currentYInt)){

                    viewTest.setX(x);
                    viewTest.setY(y);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"view X: " + currentXInt.toString()+" view Y: " + currentYInt.toString()+ "\nRect: " + 
                        viewTestRect + "\nBool: " + viewTestRect.contains(currentXInt,currentYInt),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch layout");
                return true;
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rookie mistake, I put the .get___() methods in the wrong order, should be:

Rect viewTestRect = new Rect(viewTest.getLeft(),viewTest.getTop(),viewTest.getRight(),viewTest.getBottom());

Everything works fine now.